# Cannot create a data reader for dataset 'DataSet1'

Tags: c#

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
LocalReport rep = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;

ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "DataSet1";  //this is the name of the DataSet on your report rdlc

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dataset1", ObjectDataSource1));
rep.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

Comment: I created the datasource through the report wizard already using a dataset.

Comment: Also I am trying to automate a report on a sql server using c# and it has to be web based. The end user needs to retried data based on dates.

Comment: Why not update your question with these additional tidbits, rather than add comments Spo-dee-o-dee?

Comment: Try removing the quotes from the name (DataSet1 instead of "DataSet1")

Comment: Also tell us what happens with the code you've got. So far the *only* text in the body of your question is code, but with no indication of what you're trying to do or what goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this forum. with my code I get an error "Cannot create a data reader for dataset1".  I did try your code but what do I put for this rds1.Value = dt; // Your Pass in Dataset value (type : DataTable).  Also I am pulling this data from sql server located in rackspace. I have to automate a report based on the user querying dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            LocalReport rep = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;
            rep.ReportPath = "Reports/YourReport.rdl";
            rep.DataSources.Clear();

            ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource();
            rds1.Name = "DataSet1";
            rds1.Value = dt; // Your Pass in Dataset value (type : DataTable)
            rep.DataSources.Add(rds1);
            rep.Refresh();
```